# Proper way to load properties from XML in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, xml-parsing

I have XML file with Countries stored in it. Each country element has attributes like region, subregion, country-code and more. I have service which should parse XML and get region depending on country name provided. Is there any way to load and use data from xml into memory so I don't need to parse XML everytime I want to get region for country? I don't want to use enums, because I want to have updatable xml list which is parsed only once on application startup or first time my service is used. So after XML update, server restart would be enough without any need to rebuild application to update enum. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Perhaps Jackson's XML plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@chrylis suggested this - I happen to have a similar solution lying around that's easy to copy/paste into a working example.

If your XML looks like this:

```
<countries>
    <country name="England" region="Europe"
        subregion="Western Europe" countryCode="eng" />
    <country name="Scotland" region="Europe"
        subregion="West Europe" countryCode="sco" />
</countries>
```

And you have a `Country` type thus:

```
public class Country {
    private String name;
    private String region;
    private String subregion;
    private String countryCode;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Then add the following dependency to your project:

- `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml`

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  ```

And this code:

```
public class JacksonXml {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        InputStream is = JacksonXml.class.getResourceAsStream("/countries.xml");

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

        List<Country> countries = xmlMapper.readValue(is, new TypeReference<List<Country>>() {
        });

        Map<String, Country> nameToCountry = countries.stream()
                                                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Country::getName, Function.identity()));

        System.out.println(nameToCountry.get("England")
                                        .getRegion());
    }

}
```

Will yield:

```
Europe
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resource file resources/email-templates.xml; I am accessing my file using below class,

```
package com.test.package.config;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
public class EmailTemplatesConfig {

    protected Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailTemplatesConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Bean(name = "email-templates")
    public Properties emailTemplates() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            logger.info("Loading email templates...");
            Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:email-templates.xml");
            properties.load(resource.getInputStream());

            logger.info("Loaded email templates: " + properties);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error loading email templates", e);
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Comment: How should the xml content look like?